# Making git checkout play nicely with filewatchers

Tags: git, gulp

I currently have a gulp watcher for my less + js files, which compiles less and concatenates into a minified css file, uses requirejs to build a minified js bundle, and finally bumps a `nocache.json` file.

If I run `gulp`, and try to `git checkout` and edit any css/js files in my now active branch, trying to switch back to master gives me an message saying that

`nocache.json`, `all.min.css`, `main.min.js`

have local changes (as they were generated by the filewatcher after my commit), and must be stashed before switching. I know that I can set --assume-unchanged to those files in that branch, but this seems cumbersome to do every time I create a new branch.

Was just looking for suggestions on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files probably shouldn't be part of your repository.

1. Remove them from Git (but keep them in your working copy):

   ```
   git rm --cached nocache.json all.min.css main.min.js
   ```
2. Ignore these files, so they don't accidentally get `add`ed again by adding something like this to the repository's `.gitignore` file:

   ```
   nocache.json
   # Assuming that all *.min.* files are generated from other source files
   *.min.*
   ```
3. Commit the `.gitignore` file:

   ```
   git add .gitignore
   git commit -m "Ignore generated files"
   ```

Now Git should completely ignore these files. (You will probably have to make sure that these changes affect all branches, possibly by doing them in `master` and then `merge`ing or `rebase`ing your other branches as appropriate.)

Comment: I suppose my reason for tracking them was so that they could be sent along with the rest of the deployment process. Perhaps I should just do as you suggest and remove them, and then and run gulp on the server post deploy to generate the minified files there? Would that also reduce the size of the repository?

Comment: That's what I would do. This probably won't noticeably reduce the size of your repository: (a) the files will still exist in your history, and (b) they're likely not huge files to begin with.

Comment: If the servers weren't Windows boxes.. I would be so ready to do this. I'm wondering if the potential nightmares that surround altering the production environments to use gulp are outweigh the benefits. My colleague had some difficulties compiling some of the npm gulp plugins that we are using on his windows box.